# Typescript: Typing an array of sequential middleware-like classes

Tags: node.js, typescript, middleware

I am interested in an approach to this problem:

We are given an abstract class such as:

```
    export abstract class Middleware<T, K> {
      public abstract run(input: T): Promise<K>;
    }
```

Where T is the input type, and K is the output type of `run()`. This abstract class is implemented by multiple specific middlewares. All middlewares are stored in an array, for sequential execution, such as:

```
    [
      specificMiddleware1,
      specificMiddleware2,
      specificMiddleware3
    ]
```

Where the output type `K` of `specificMiddleware1` will be the same as the input type `T` of `specificMiddleware2`, and so on.

All middlewares should be added to this array, so this is the best place to enforce type safety.

How could I enforce the return type of an array element to be the input type of the next one. Is there any way to do this in typescript?

Right now, I am using a more manual approach, where I have to manually maintain the input and output types:

```
    export type InputType = //some type;
    export type OutputType1 = //some type;
    export type OutputType2 = //some type;
    export type OutputType3 = //some type;
    
    export interface Schema {
      middlewares: [
        // specificMiddleware1
        Middleware<InputType, OutputType1>,
        // specificMiddleware2
        Middleware<OutputType1, OutputType2>,
        // specificMiddleware3
        Middleware<OutputType2, OutputType3>,
      ]
    }
```

This works fine, but gets more and more cumbersome as more middlewares are added.
This also allows `specificMiddleware1` to have a return type that does not match the input type of `specificMiddleware2`, so I am losing type safety there.

**Edit 1**
I have tried out this awkward thing, but operations like these do not work in types, and I don't think this is feasible in a generic way. Probably I could make it work by knowing all types.

```
type Numbers = { 0;  1;  2; };

export type MiddlewareList = {
  [Index in keyof Numbers]: Middleware<
    ReturnType<MiddlewareList[Index - 1]['run']>,
    unknown
  >;
};
```

**Edit 2:**
I have achieved a rather crude solution, and I will post it here for visibility. If you have any suggestions, I'm open to hearing them

```
// Returns the type T from Promise<T>
export type ExtractPromiseResult<T = PromiseLike<any>> = T extends PromiseLike<infer R> ? R : never;

// Returns the type K from 
// public abstract run(input: T): Promise<K>;
export type ExtractReturnType<T> = ExtractPromiseResult<ReturnType<T['run']>>

export type MiddlewareChain<
  InputType,
  Middleware1 extends Middleware<unknown, unknown>,
  Middleware2 extends Middleware<unknown, unknown> = never, // using never as default allows it to be optional
  Middleware3 extends Middleware<unknown, unknown> = never, // using never as default allows it to be optional
  // ... extend as needed
> = [
  Middleware<InputType, ExtractReturnType<Middleware1>>,
  Middleware<ExtractReturnType<Middleware1>, ExtractReturnType<Middleware2>>?,
  Middleware<ExtractReturnType<Middleware2>, ExtractReturnType<Middleware3>>?,
  // ... extend as needed
];
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a solution for that, and I don't think there is since even respected libraries (such as [rxjs](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/pipe.ts)) just type them out manually until some arbitrary limit.

Comment: `K` as a type parameter is conventionally used to mean a keylike type; unless you're using it as a key (e.g., `{[P in K]: ...}` or `Record<K, ...>`) then it's distracting and confusing.  Could you maybe change it to `U` which is more conventional?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m0YPxW) meet your needs?  It looks strictly better than your `MiddlewareChain` type, but your code doesn't have enough use cases for me to know for sure, and your reply to the existing answer gives me pause that what you're doing is even possible unless you have *some* compile-time knowledge of the middleware list.  I'm happy to write up an answer explaining my `MiddlewareList` type, or continue looking at other options if you can [edit] to provide some concrete use cases to test against.  How would you like to proceed?

Comment: @jcalz It does appear to be working fine, and it does feel more elegant than what I did produce, although I am now more fond of passing the actual Middlewares as a generic to the MiddlewareChain, as opposed to searching for each specific type inside a middleware and compiling a list as in your example. Perhaps I can adapt it. Could you update your snippet with some comments, as I don't really understand how it works? Thanks

Comment: I can either post an answer explaining how it works, or I can go away unless I see some [edit]s to the question with testable use cases.  I'm not going to spend a lot of time adding explanations to things that only appear in comments. How would you like to proceed?

Comment: @jcalz post an answer, looks like it's what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to transform a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of types like `[string, number, boolean, Date]` into a corresponding chain of `Middleware` types like `[Middleware<string, number>, Middleware<number, boolean>, Middleware<boolean, Date>]`, you can do so via a [(tail-)recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that uses [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types).  Here's one way:

```
type MiddlewareList<
   T extends readonly any[], 
   M extends readonly Middleware<any, any>[] = []
> = T extends readonly [infer T0, infer T1, ...infer R] ?
    MiddlewareList<[T1, ...R], [...M, Middleware<T0, T1>]> :
    M
```

The type `MiddlewareList<T, M>` takes a tuple type `T` and an *accumulator* tuple `M` which is intended to start off as empty (hence the [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of the empty tuple `[]`, with `M = []`) and which accumulates intermediate results.

It uses [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) with variadic tuple types to parse the `T` tuple into its first two elements `T0` and `T1`, and the rest of the tuple `R`.  If that fails then there are fewer than two elements in the list and we just return our accumulator `M`.  If it succeeds then we recursively call `MiddlewareList<[T1, ...R], [...M, Middleware<T0, T1>]>`.  That is, we drop only `T0` from the beginning of `T`, and we append `Middleware<T0, T1>` to the end of `M`.

---

First, let's make sure this works before stepping through it:

```
type Z = MiddlewareList<[string, number, boolean, Date]>;
// type Z = [
//   Middleware<string, number>, Middleware<number, boolean>, Middleware<boolean, Date>
// ]
```

---

Looks good.  Okay, now let's walk through the evaluation step-by-step so you can hopefully see how it works:

```
MiddlewareList<[string, number, boolean, Date]>`
```

evaluates to

```
MiddlewareList<[string, number, boolean, Date], []>`
```

because of the default type argument.  That then evaluates to

```
[string, number, boolean, Date] extends readonly [infer T0, infer T1, ...infer R] ?
MiddlewareList<[T1, ...R], [...[], Middleware<T0, T1>]> : []
```

The conditional check succeeds with `T0` being `string`, `T1` being `number`, and `R` being `[boolean, Date]` (note that mutable tuple types are seen as assignable to [`readonly` tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types)), so it then becomes

```
MiddlewareList<[number, ...[boolean, Date]], [...[], Middleware<string, number>]>
```

which, when we evaluate those variadic tuples to normal forms, is

```
MiddlewareList<[number, boolean, Date], [Middleware<string, number>]>.
```

So in the first step, `string` was shifted off the front of `T` and used along with `number` to make a `Middleware<string, number>` type pushed onto the end of `M`.

Analogously you can hopefully see how this then becomes

```
MiddlewareList<
  [boolean, Date], 
  [Middleware<string, number>, Middleware<number, boolean>]
>
```

and then

```
MiddlewareList<
  [Date], 
  [Middleware<string, number>, Middleware<number, boolean>, Middleware<boolean, Date>]
>
```

at which point the conditional type check fails, because `[Date]` does not extend `readonly [infer T0, infer T1, ...infer R]`.  And so this just evaluates to `M` alone, which is now the full accumulated

```
[Middleware<string, number>, Middleware<number, boolean>, Middleware<boolean, Date>]
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwEYGcZQQY3pgNglFOAWQEsATc3YAdwSmAB4AVAGjgFUA+OAbwCg4QuGACuSXKUyJU6LPCiiAdgApSSsTABccZgEodABSgQAtqRRNuAbn4BffvxgBPMMBIUqtesAAyFmBY4UBhgJXIiBgRyCCVcZ0QlZwBtAF12YmCQUPDI4GjY+I9KajoGRgQk9krnLjS4AF44NJ4GwWFmLJyIuCiYuITk9QAzYChdAAZ2EbHdAEZ2ADplmfGAJVS4AH52oTIS7wZ-NEZk5gW4ZcWN9mSr4gzPUp8WKfmuVJ4tXZJHFzc4AAtRrFLxlPwBU5oKDqADm7CUolMSDG7CQEAg1Eq7AAIghQp9bAB6Ilwf7uYFNZL7MEvaFwhFIlFQLiPA7gxiI5GouDozH5JSs0HPcp8rFKXH44AfRxAA)

Comment: This is lovely and seems to be exactly what I need. I am looking into adapting it so I can pass actual Middleware types in the array, as opposed to its generics.

Comment: I have managed something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQ2AnN). But while it seems to be working in the playground, in my app running TypeScript 4.6.4, it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple or good solution for this problem. You can try to do it using recursive types, but I'm not sure if it's even possible. You can look in the direction of `pipe`, `compose`, `flow` and other similar function in functional programming libraries. (i.e. https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/function.ts.html#pipe)

In my opinion, the most typescript way to do this would be replace array

one way is to have method like `chain`

```js
interface Middleware<Input, Output> {
  run(input: Input): Output;

  chain<NextOutput>(
    middleware: Middleware<Output, NextOutput>
  ): Middleware<Input, NextOutput>;
}

//

const middleware = specificMiddleware1
  .chain(specificMiddleware2)
  .chain(specificMiddleware3)
```

Another way is to use trick with chaining methods and changing `this` type. But it's a bit more awkward and you have to do unsafe type cast:

```js
class MiddlewareBuilder<Input, Output> {
  private middlewares: Middleware<unknown, unknown>[];

  // we have to provide 1 middleware right away to initialize Builder with types
  constructor(middleware: Middleware<Input, Output>) {
    this.middlewares = [middleware];
  }

  addMiddleware<NewOutput>(
    middleware: Middleware<Output, NewOutput>
  ): MiddlewareBuilder<Input, NewOutput> {
    this.middlewares.push(middleware);

    return this as unknown as MiddlewareBuilder<Input, NewOutput>;
  }

  build() {
    return this.middlewares;
  }
}

const middlewares = new MiddlewareBuilder(specificMiddleware1)
  .addMiddleware(specificMiddleware2)
  .addMiddleware(specificMiddleware3)
  .build();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for my use-case, this isn't really feasible. I have some logic that determines which `Schema` to use, and then loads the middlewares array and calls each of them subsequentially. This is all runtime, so I doubt type safety is possible.

I have tried out this awkward thing (see edit), but subtractions like that don't work. And I think it wouldn't really work generically without knowing all types.